# Add a suffix number after each iteration when writing pandas data frame to excel file

Tags: python, pandas

I'm performing calculations on a double for loop that has a unique list of products and unique list of customers. I want to write out each pandas data frame of the product/customer combo to an excel file and add a number each time by 1. So essentially something like

```
   for product in product_list:
       for customer in customer_list:
           dataframe = data[(data.Product==product) & (data.Customer==customer)]
           # read to excel file:
           dataframe.to_excel('df1.xlsx)
```

where the code would write out the first dataframe and call it 'df1.xlsx', then 'df2.xlsx', df3.xlsx', etc.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could easily add some sort of counter like this.

```py
   cnt = 0
   for product in product_list:
       for customer in customer_list:
           dataframe = data[(data.Product==product) & (data.Customer==customer)]
           # read to excel file:
           cnt += 1
           dataframe.to_excel(f'df{cnt}.xlsx')
```

However, why not add the product and customer to the filename(s) so you can they be more easily identifiable?

```py
dataframe.to_excel(f'{product}-{customer}.xlsx')
```

Comment: does the cnt +=1 stay inside the double for loop? When I try the proposed solution, it just keeps printing 1 over and over when I print(cnt)

Comment: Where have you put the initial declaration for `cnt`? That should be before both loops.